# Could not build Objective-C module 'YogaKit'

Tags: objective-c, react-native, podio

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform: ios, '12.4'
prepare_react_native_project!
  pod 'mailcore2-ios'
pod 'GTMOAuth2',: modular_headers => true
pod 'GTMAppAuth',: modular_headers => true
pod 'YogaKit'

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
use_react_native!(: flipper_configuration => ENV['CI'] ?
  FlipperConfiguration.disabled :
  FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
  # Note: you also can pass extra params #FlipperConfiguration.enabled(['Debug', 'Staging.Debug'], {
    'Flipper': '0.174.0'
  })
)
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS]
if linkage != nil
Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green use_frameworks!: linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Mailcore'
do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks!: linkage =>: static

$static_framework = ['FlipperKit', 'Flipper', 'Flipper-Folly',
  'CocoaAsyncSocket', 'ComponentKit', 'DoubleConversion',
  'glog', 'Flipper-PeerTalk', 'Flipper-RSocket', 'Yoga', 'YogaKit',
  'CocoaLibEvent', 'openssl-ios-bitcode', 'boost-for-react-native'
]
# Flags change depending on the env values.
flags = get_default_flags()

use_react_native!(: path => config[: reactNativePath],
  # Hermes is now enabled by
  default.Disable by setting this flag to false.# Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.: hermes_enabled => flags[: hermes_enabled],: fabric_enabled => flags[: fabric_enabled],
  # Enables Flipper.# # Note that
  if you have use_frameworks!enabled, Flipper will not work and # you should disable the next line.#: flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.disabled,
  # An absolute path to your application root.: app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
)

target 'MailcoreTests'
do
  inherit!: complete
# Pods
for testing
end

post_install do | installer |
  react_native_post_install(
    installer,
    # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled`
    to `true` in order to apply patches # necessary
    for Mac Catalyst builds: mac_catalyst_enabled => false
  )
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do | config |
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end
end
end
```

Here is my pod file, I am Stuck on *Could not build Objective-C module 'YogaKit'* was trying to do bridging for macos tried removing pod lock file , clean rebuild doesn't work.

i am using use_frameworks!, so i disabled flipper that resolved Flipper issues but after that this issue occured.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue on GitHub that discusses a similar problem where YogaKit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36185) is not installed when Flipper is disabled. In the meantime - Try clearing your derived data and reinstalling your pods.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```